# SQL2000 - Manually installing

Tags: sql-server

I am manually installing from sql server 2000 standard X86 SETUP, I see EXE & LST folders and several other applications , DBG files, INS files, configuration settings ., HDR files, DAT files etc. Which file will help me to install correctly?
Never done this before, but I need to connect using SQL Enterprise Manager 2000 for SQL2000.
thanks

Comment: This version isn't even supported now, why do you want to install it?

Comment: I needed to install to access certain packages under data transformation services.

Comment: Ah. Look at this. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51958

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since I've done that, but Setup.exe in root directory is my best recollection, and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btMi6LaIJuM) seems to confirm.